# Hide div on WordPress specific page

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I want to hide a div on a specific WordPress page by overriding the original CSS. This is my code:

```
   body.page-id-7 #thumbnails .controls { display: none !important; }
```

However this does not work. #thumbnails is the id of a Div which contains another div with the class "controls". Any idea why this does not work. The page I am looking at is http://who.designbond.co.uk/ and I want to hide the arrows at the bottom right of that specific page.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hmmm, checked your page with ID of 7. Seems to work for me. Are you sure you arent looking at the page cached? Try clearing your browser cache. I assume that your link is wrong and that you want it to work for your page with ID of 7. Otherwise you need to change your CSS-class to: `.home` instead of `.page-id-7`

Comment: Hi, I cleared the cache and checked on 2 different PCs and the arrows on the bottom right of the page are still there. I want to hide them only on that page (whose id = 7) but the above code it does not work for me.

Comment: Add this: `.page-id-7.fullsize-gallery #colophon .keynav{ display: none!important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the home page you want to hide this on, this should be enough:

```
.home .controls {display: none;}
```

The home page `body` element doesn't have a class of `page-id-7`, though, so I wonder if I'm looking at the right page?

Comment: page-id-7 is not the class, but Worpress page id

Comment: I don't see `page-id-7` on any of your pages, but there are similar ones on other pages, and they are all classes. You have targeted `page-id-7` as a class in your CSS above (because you put a dot before it). Can you indicate which page you are actually referring to? (You linked to your home page and said that was the page you were having trouble with.)

Comment: I found this thread (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/hiding-a-div-element-on-a-specific-page-only) and used the same code. I thought that you can reference the page id from the css. I want to hide that div only on the home page, however at this point I guess I need to find another way.

Comment: Hi Ralph, you were right. I was referencing the page id, whereas I should have reference the page by its post name.

Answer (score 0):

add to CSS `.rel .controls {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
 body.home.fullsize-gallery #thumbnails .controls { display: none !important; }
```

I was referencing the page by its id, whereas I should have referenced the page by its post name, that is "home".